Sentry with WebPack results in no source context on Sentry
UPDATE: My sourcemap https://pastebin.com/vj3EHTMV
PS. I have just added inlineSources to true on tsconfig.json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["es2023", "dom"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2023",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./app/*"]
    }
  }
}

I have added Sentry to my serverless project which make use of WebPack, I can see the errors on Sentry's console, however, I can not have a preview of the source code as I can have on Python for exameple.
Is it possible to have the source code embedded?
I have done some research on Sentry's documentation, no luck.

My webpack config:
/* global __dirname */
/* global module */
/* global require */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-require-imports */
const path = require("path");
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");

const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const { sentryWebpackPlugin } = require("@sentry/webpack-plugin");

/** @type { import('webpack').Configuration } */
module.exports = {
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? "development" : "production",
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  // devtool: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-source-map',
  devtool: "source-map",
  target: "node",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts"], // we just need TypeScript
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()],
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
    path: path.join(__dirname, ".webpack"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  externals: ["aws-sdk", nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: [
          /node_modules/,
          path.resolve(__dirname, ".webpack"),
          path.resolve(__dirname, ".serverless"),
        ],
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true,
          experimentalFileCaching: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
    new CopyPlugin({ patterns: [{ from: "google.json", to: "google.json" }] }),
    sentryWebpackPlugin({
      org: "zoomies",
      project: "serverless",
      authToken: process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
      telemetry: false,
    }),
  ],
};


Can you check if your source maps are correctly generated and uploaded to Sentry? You may also want to ensure that the source maps are properly configured in your Sentry Webpack plugin settings.
The sentry-webpack-plugin should automatically upload your source maps when you build your application.

I will double check the source map generation and upload.

Regarding the Sentry configuration, where can I check?

I can see the source maps on Sentry, all of them, however, they are not linked to the crash

Are you using a sourceMappingURL comment or header to link the map to the source? Make sure the paths are correct. Can you share one of the source maps?

I have updated my question with the source map, or you can check here https://pastebin.com/vj3EHTMV

So how are you linking app/v1/receiver/http/crash.js to the source map? With the SourceMap http header or the sourceMappingURL inline comment? You might need to make use of the plugins rewriteSources option.

Check this issue: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript-bundler-plugins/issues/430

Thank you. I have added rewriteSources: (source) => source,, however no luck...
